# What's the latest time you should schedule an interview?

Tags: interviewing, scheduling

I have a phone interview with a company for 60 minutes and have the choice to select the date. Is it ok if I schedule the interview 1.5 weeks from today or is that too late of an interview date since I have midterms going on right now.

Comment: What kind of job? You can get away with two weeks if it's a hard to fill opening, but they might find someone else in that time if it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.5 weeks is fine.  1.5 months would be a little excessive.

There's nothing wrong with selecting a date and telling your interviewer you wanted to wait until after midterms.

Comment: Just remember to confirm the time the week of in case something changed on their end.

Comment: Many people seem to think interviewers are a lot less reasonable than they are, for some reason. They know that life happens.

Comment: Your Midterms should be of concern to them too, if not somewhere else will be interested (or why take the course). If they hire continuously you can join in the next round. Try to schedule 15 mins. for a looksee (meet and greet) then you can quickly assess how much time you would spend and what's a priority. Sometimes midterms can be pushed back, giving you more time to study. I asked for months off before my finals and came back a half dozen times to finish the various parts - school was OK with that (and my attendance/marks). If you're just getting out of school you've a lot more ahead.